# PHP Decryption of Rijndael 256 from .NET

Tags: php, encryption, rijndael

I am getting a base64 encoded Token from a .NET Website and wish to decode it in PHP. I received the Key and the IV from the programmer but I can't get the decryption to work. I read a lot about problems with padding but none of the suggested solutions seemed to work for my problem - I just can't get the text decrypted.

```
function decryptToken($decoded, $key, $iv){

    $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $decoded,
            MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    return $decrypted;
}
```

The parameters are the base64_decode($token) and the decoded Key and IV.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show how exactly you call `decryptToken()`?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't encrypted with AES-256 (i.e. block-size=128, not 256)? And do you have the .net source code for the encryption?

Comment: "I received [...] the IV from the programmer" Does that mean you're using a constant "IV"? That's not how an IV works. An IV should be a random value that's different each time you run the encryption function. | I also think it's very likely that one can use a padding oracle to decrypt your tokens without knowing the key.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes we are using a constant "IV" right now, as soon as we get it to decrypt the data, we will send it along every time.

Comment: @jack
$decryptedToken = $this->decryptToken($token, base64_decode(...), base64_decode(...));

Comment: Your variable names are horribly chosen and it's probably best to create a simple script that exhibits the problem. The .Net code would also help.

Comment: I will try to get access to the .NET code, I am following up on the AES-256 block-size trace(using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 instead), key is 32byte, iv is 16 byte.
Don't worry about the variable names etc for now, all that will change, once the logic works properly.